# $\mathcal{F}(Z(f)) \cong \mathbb{C}[X]/f(X)\mathbb{C}[X]$ for hypersurface $\mathcal{F}(Z(f))$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{C}[X] = \mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ be the polynomial ring in $n$ variables over the complex numbers. An irreducible hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is the solution set $Z(f)$ of $f(x) = 0, f$ an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[X].$ Let $\mathcal{F}(Z(f))$ denote the ring of complex valued polynomial functions on the hypersuface $Z(f)$; i.e. $h \in \mathcal{F}(Z(f))$ iff $\exists g \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ such that $h(T) = g(T)$ for all $T \in Z(f)$. Prove that $\mathcal{F}(Z(f)) \cong \mathbb{C}[X]/f(X)\mathbb{C}[X]$

It seems to me that based on the definition of  $\mathcal{F}(Z(f))$ it doesn't necessarily even need to be a polynomial, since $h$ just has to equal to a complex polynomial on the solution set of $f$. So I don't see how the desired statement can be true.

Comment: Context?  Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If $h \in \mathbb C[x_1, ... , x_n]$ is a polynomial, then $h$ determines a function $\underline{h}:Z(f) \rightarrow \mathbb C$ by restriction.  Clearly $\underline{h} \in \mathcal F(Z(f))$.  This map $h \mapsto \underline{h}$ is a ring homomorphism

$$\mathbb C[x_1, ... , x_n] \rightarrow \mathcal F(Z(f)).$$

Obviously, it is surjective.  Now, show its kernel is the ideal generated by $f$.